# Test non static methods in Rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Is it possible to check what arguments is being passed to a non static method when testing with rspec?

If I for i.e want to test class A, inside class A i call class B, B is already tested. The only thing I want to test is the ingoing arguments to B.

```
class A
  def method
    number = 10
    b = B.new
    b.calling(number)
  end
end

class B
  def calling(argument)
    # This code in this class is already testet
  end
end
```

How do I test the ingoing arguments to `b.calling`?

I've tried this so far, without success.

```
it "should work" do
  b = mock(B)
  b.should_receive(:calling).at_least(1).times
  A.new.method
end
```

It always fails, beacuse `b` never was called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the b in your spec isn't the b A is instantiating (it returns a real instance of B when you call new since you haven't stubbed it), try this:

```
it "should work" do
  b = mock(B)
  B.should_receive(:new).and_return(b)
  b.should_receive(:calling).at_least(1).times
  A.new.method
end
```

Comment: +1, although the OP should really ask himself why `A` knows to how construct `B` s in the first place. Or why `method` constructs a `B` and then immediately throws it away.

Comment: Yes, though I think it's a pathological/pedagogical example. It would be more usual to see asserting a call on b when it is passed as an argument, like a.method(b).